# Bulk API - Upload documents (files and URL) through CSV

Tags: bulk-api, upload, document, bulk

I have tried uploading files through CSV using Bulk API's `createBatchWithFileattachment()` call. It basically goes like this:

```
createBatchWithFileAttachments(JobInfo jobInfo, InputStream batchContent, File rootDirectory,
        String... files)
```

Documents can be either files or the URLs. This particular call is used for uploading files through CSVs. If there is a document that is of the type 'URL', the body field is empty and the call returns FileNotFoundException(). Is there a way that I can create a job that encompasses both files and non-files through Bulk API?

This is with reference for Bulk API class mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_code_walkthrough.htm):

> To import binary attachments, use the following methods. Specify the
>   CSV, XML, or JSON content for the batch in the batchContent parameter,
>   or include request.txt in the attached files and pass null to the
>   batchContent parameter. These methods are contained within the
>   com.async.BulkConnection class:
>
> ```
> createBatchFromDir()
> createBatchWithFileAttachments()
> createBatchWithInputStreamAttachments()
> createBatchFromZipStream()
> ```

EDIT: Solution is to use the existing method mentioned (Thanks to Daniel). I am able to write a separate utility that does this:

```
private BatchInfo createBatchFromFiles(JobInfo job, Path fileDir, List<String> paths, Path newCsv)
            throws AsyncApiException, IOException
    {

        Map<String, InputStream> attachments = new HashMap<>();
        for (String path : paths)
        {
            Path filePath = fileDir.resolve(path);
            if (Files.exists(filePath))
                attachments.put(path, Files.newInputStream(filePath));
            else
                attachments.put(path, new ByteArrayInputStream("".getBytes()));
        }

        return ConnectionManager.getBulkConnection().createBatchWithInputStreamAttachments(job,
                Files.newInputStream(newCsv), attachments);
    }
```

Note that the CSV under the body field should contain the data as "#" for a document and "" (empty string) for a URL.

Comment: Where is the `createBatchWithFileAttachments` method defined? Is it from a library?

Comment: @DanielBallinger It is from Bulk API class (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_code_walkthrough.htm). Please refer to the highlighted one "These methods are contained within the com.async.BulkConnection class"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see in the source for BulkConnection the version of [`createBatchWithFileAttachments`](https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc/blob/08dc81a4add05e9aee1654050503233055ec4b5c/src/main/java/com/sforce/async/BulkConnection.java#L264) you are calling.

That method attempts to use the string file as a path relative to the `rootDirectory`. That wouldn't make so much sense for a URL.

Instead have a look at the [alternative method](https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc/blob/08dc81a4add05e9aee1654050503233055ec4b5c/src/main/java/com/sforce/async/BulkConnection.java#L301):

```
  public BatchInfo createBatchWithInputStreamAttachments(JobInfo jobInfo, InputStream batchContent,
        Map<String, InputStream> attachments)
```

You will need to create your own InputStream for each file or URL to pull them in appropriately.

Comment: This worked! A note is that body field under the CSV should not contain any content.